# Applicative vs Generative functors

Tags: functional-programming, terminology, sml, functor

I have recently been learning SML, when I came to know the terms - **applicative** and **generative functors**. I also know that SML uses **generative** functors.

I tried to Google the terms but couldn't find any compelling resources that explains what these terms mean and what are the differences between the two.

So, I just wanted to know the actual meaning of these terms in some practically understable way and how this relates to SML being **generative**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has to do with equality of abstract types in the module resulting from functor application.

Generative means that two invocations of a functor will produce modules containing non-equal abstract types.

Applicative means that two invocations of a functor will produce modules containing equal abstract types *if* the arguments are equal in some sense (such as being syntactically identical).

I'll give an example in OCaml, since it happens to support both:

```
module App (M : sig end) : sig
  type t
  val zero : t
end = struct
  type t = int
  let zero = 0
end

(* A () argument signifies a generative functor in OCaml. *)
module Gen (M : sig end) () : sig
  type t
  val zero : t
end = struct
  type t = int
  let zero = 0
end

module Empty = struct end

module A = App (Empty)
module B = App (Empty)
module C = App (struct end) (* The argument is syntactically different. *)

module D = Gen (Empty) ()
module E = Gen (Empty) ()

let _ = begin
  (* A.t and B.t are compatible. *)
  ignore (A.zero = B.zero);  (* OK *)

  (* A.t and C.t are not compatible because the functor arguments
   * are not syntactically equal. *)
  ignore (A.zero = C.zero);  (* type error *)

  (* D.t and C.t are not compatible because they are produced
   * from generative functors. *)
  ignore (D.zero = E.zero); (* type error *)
end
```